# Would a WhatsApp chat popup affect rankings?

Tags: seo, chat, google-algorithm, pop-up

One of my new websites is now ranking on the 1st page. If I put a WhatsApp chat popup on the website, would it affect the rankings?  Do Google algorithms consider that chat as lead generation and penalize it?

Has anyone test this or have any experience with it?

[Plugin Link](https://codecanyon.net/item/whatsapp-click-to-chat-for-wordpress/20248537)

Comment: What is the purpose of this popup?   Is this a customer service offering?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have added the plugin link

Comment: So for customer support.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes